# Execute Script after two separate ADFv2 Pipelines have completed

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have two ADFv2 Pipelines that import data into two seperate srl tables within an Azure SQL database. Once both the pipelines have completed I would need to execute a script.

The source .csv files that initiates the execution of each individual pipeline will be created on a daily basis, but I can only execute the script when both Pipelines have completed...

each seperate pipeline is triggered via a Logic App by the creation of a seperate .csv file

I can use Logic Apps as well, but at the moment I can't find the best process to implement this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of script? A SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

2 situation:

1.If you don't mind the pipeline linear execution,you could use Execute Pipeline Activity. Execute function until the first two Execute Pipeline Activity executes successfully, like this process:

[image]

2.If not, my idea is using queue trigger. After pipeline execution, send a message to [azure queue storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) by for example Web Activity([REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Queue-Service-REST-API?redirectedfrom=MSDN)). Configure a function queue trigger, judge if it receive 2 successful messages,then do some jobs.

Of course, you could use [ADF monitor SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically) to de-polling to check the execution status and results of two pipelines and do the next jobs. You could pick a suitable solution.

Besides, you could get an idea of Logic App as you mentioned in the answer.It supports run after for 2 connectors. Both of them are successful, then do the next job.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay. 

I'm unable to use your first suggestion as each seperate pipeline is triggered via a Logic App by the creation of a seperate .csv file. There is no fixed time for when either of the .csv's could be delivered and so it would be a matter of executing each pipeline seperately. The question would then be how to execute the script.

I also had the idea of creating a 'flag' table in which I create a record after each of the pipeline had finished and then this somehow executing the script when the rowcount is two. But this seems rather convoluted.

Comment: I added some information to your original question which you only made obvious in this comment. Anyway... what kind of script do you want to trigger (T-SQL?) Do you absolutely have to trigger the import of both files from logic apps? There's no way to avoid having a control table in this case, but then you need to ensure it never gets 'stuck'

Comment: Thanks Nick.
I've not posted that much on here so thanks for the heads up the fact I can add more info to the original question.

I'm not sure what you mean by a control table. I don't have to trigger both pipelines via Logic Apps, but I do need the pipelines to run as soon as the csv's are created within an on-premise folder. Once both have been loaded I would need to execute a stored procedure to merge the two tables together into another table via a view. This final table must only contain data from both loads.